# I get error when I update the third click activity in tabwidget

Tags: android, android-intent, refresh

I have a problem. I have two refresh button in differents activities that It work but when I click the third time, I have a error. Is it necessary put a cursor for control it?

code for refresh:

```
refrescar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)              {
Intent anterior = getIntent();
anterior.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
View vista = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("registratsi", anterior).getDecorView();
setContentView(vista);
  }
});
```

> 06-13 07:22:59.904: E/src(315):
>
> 06-13 07:23:01.384: D/dalvikvm(315): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5105
>   objects / 356600 bytes in 60ms 06-13 07:23:02.315: E/Bitmap(315):
>   returned 06-13 07:23:02.334: E/src(315):
>
> 06-13 07:23:02.694: E/Bitmap(315): returned 06-13 07:23:02.704:
>   E/src(315):
>
> 06-13 07:23:03.084: E/Bitmap(315): returned 06-13 07:23:03.095:
>   E/src(315):
>
> 06-13 07:23:03.424: E/dalvikvm-heap(315): 531392-byte external
>   allocation too large for this process. 06-13 07:23:03.424:
>   E/GraphicsJNI(315): VM won't let us allocate 531392 bytes 06-13
>   07:23:03.424: D/skia(315): --- decoder->decode returned false 06-13
>   07:23:03.424: D/AndroidRuntime(315): Shutting down VM 06-13
>   07:23:03.424: W/dalvikvm(315): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 06-13 07:23:03.464:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(315): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-13 07:23:03.464:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(315): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds
>   VM budget 06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):  at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method) 06-13
>   07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):  at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:459)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:515)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.Registrat.getBitmapFromURL(Registrat.java:227)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.Registrat.onCreate(Registrat.java:96)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.Registrat$2.onClick(Registrat.java:166)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) 06-13 07:23:03.464:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) 06-13 07:23:03.464:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 06-13
>   07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 06-13
>   07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 06-13 07:23:03.464:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 06-13
>   07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-13
>   07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 06-13 07:23:03.464:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   06-13 07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 06-13
>   07:23:03.464: E/AndroidRuntime(315):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

other botton:

```
    btnReload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()          {           @Override           public void onClick(View arg0)              { //                >Intent anterior = getIntent();
            Intent anterior = new Intent (webPushActivity.this, webPushActivity.class);
             View vista = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("social",
                     anterior)
                        .getDecorView(); 
                   setContentView(vista);           }       });
```

other error :

> 06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.nimbosolutions.projecte1/com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.webPushActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 06-13 09:50:13.493:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.webPushActivity$3.onClick(webPushActivity.java:177)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) 06-13 09:50:13.493:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) 06-13 09:50:13.493:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 06-13
>   09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 06-13
>   09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 06-13 09:50:13.493:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 06-13
>   09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-13
>   09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 06-13 09:50:13.493:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 06-13
>   09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-13 09:50:13.493:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1274): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.webPushActivity.onCreate(webPushActivity.java:71)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   06-13 09:50:13.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):   ... 15 more

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you post the stack trace of the error (all of it), then we could try to see what's wrong.

Comment: I have already put this code. Thanks! ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a bitmap, and the following line says what's wrong:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget 06-13 07:23:03.464:
```

Maybe you are creating too many bitmaps. Or your bitmaps are too large. In older versions of Android, there was a bug in the bitmapFactory throwing these memory errors even when you created the second bitmap, so you had to recycle all bitmaps. Newer versions of Android don't seem to have that issues, or maybe that's because there's more memory now.

Try creating only one bitmap, and recycle it after use. If you use more than one bitmap, make sure you downsize them to the size you need. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For this exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget 06-13 07:23:03.464:
```

I have given my answer [bitmap size exceeds Vm budget error android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115). Please go through it, it should solve your problem.

Thank you :)