# ImageView OutofMemoryException 

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have a problem when inserting an image in an ImageView. I have tried several ways to solve it but it still fails, the latest version follows. The image size is 3000x3000.

Code:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);  
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.prueba_plano_2).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
iv.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);
```

XML:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlayer" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="matrix" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:374)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:404)
06-21 09:32:06.721: E/AndroidRuntime(25709):    at 

.............
```

Comment: see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115

Comment: you can't use such a big image. You have to scale it before using it

Comment: then you should use the search box before asking.

Comment: @Shrikant But my problem is on load, not on change the orientation

Comment: @AndroSelva after searching I found that adding ARGB_8888 I can work with images of that size without reducing

Comment: you should scale the image http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Yeah that question is regarding orientation change, but the image has to get loaded on orientation change, so on that same issue of OOME I have given some other solution on it as well, please check those, it might help you to solve it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max size of a bitmap is 2048x2048, if your bitmap is bigger than this you should scale it..
I'm using this method to scale a bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmapToScale, float newWidth, float newHeight) {   
    if(bitmapToScale == null)
        return null;
    //get the original width and height
    int width = bitmapToScale.getWidth();
    int height = bitmapToScale.getHeight();
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(newWidth / width, newHeight / height);

    // recreate the new Bitmap and set it back
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapToScale, 0, 0, bitmapToScale.getWidth(), bitmapToScale.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

You can also check the memory state using this:

```
ActivityManager actMgr = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo minfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
actMgr.getMemoryInfo(minfo);
if(minfo.lowMemory) { //do something}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also load the image dimension without loading the complete image.

```
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new
    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options();

options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
```

Now you have the image dimension available via:

```
options.outHeight
options.outWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the official Android Developer docs:**Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently** in this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html),Given that you are working with limited memory (mobile phones), ideally you only have to load a lower resolution version in memory. Follow the advices posted in the link and you will avoid your OM problem