# Base64 image not displayed in android imageview

Tags: android, xamarin.android, imageview, base64

I am trying to show the base64 image in image view but it doesn't display. I am decoding and setiing image bitmap of the imageview. 
I am dynamically adding imageviews. Is the issue because of Iam adding images dynamiclly?
Below is the code snippet:

```
LayoutInflater inflaterDocuments = (LayoutInflater)GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
View inflatedHeaderLayout = inflaterDocuments.Inflate(Resource.Layout.imageListItem, null, false);
ImageView imageView = inflatedHeaderLayout.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
byte[] decodedString = Base64.Decode(base64String, Base64Flags.Default);
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.Length);
imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitMap);
imageView.Invalidate();
_imageLayout.AddView(inflatedHeaderLayout);
```

**Edit**

Base64 string file [Base64.txt](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09812369877440514110)

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is method to get base64**

```
public static String getBase64String(Bitmap image) {
    String encodeString = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encodeString;
}
```

**Glide use for show Image**

```
String photoId = base64;
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(photoId)
            .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
            .into(employeeImage);
```

Comment: What is Glide? I am doing it in Xamarin android.

Comment: implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
add this in your gradle file. It's is an easy way to manage image view.

Comment: Where do I have to set it to imageview? What is employeeImage is it imageview?

Comment: add this is oncreate
 ImageView employeeImage = findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

Comment: if doesn't work check your base64 image in online. I think you fixed the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187551/discussion-between-masum-and-arti).

Comment: I have uploaded base64 string file. Please take a look.

Comment: If your string is correct then use glide. I already use it and it's work.

Comment: I am trying it on Xiaomi Redmi 6A phone with android version 8.1.0. Could it be an issue?

Comment: maybe not. You can use an emulator instead of the phone.

Comment: Emulator is way too slow.

Comment: Is it possible to set base64 as Url to imageview?

Comment: no. It declares as a string. so you can only  use string.

Answer (score -1):

Create method to convert `Base64` to `Bitmap`

```
public Bitmap BaseStringToBitmap(string imageBase64)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64);
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
}
```

Than use it on `ImageView` object

```
imageView.SetImageBitmap(BaseStringToBitmap(base64String));
```

Sample code

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    var iv = FindViewById<Android.Widget.ImageView>(Resource.Id.image1);
    iv.SetImageBitmap(BaseStringToBitmap());
}   
public Bitmap BaseStringToBitmap()
{
    var bse64 = "/9j/4ZT8RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAARAA4BAgAgAAAA2gAAAA8BAgAgAAAA...";
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bse64);
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
}
```

Axml file

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image1"
android:background="#89CFF0"    
android:layout_width="200dp" 
android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

Output screenshot

[image]

Comment: @Arti - Can you please provide `base64` string in text file or some other way, so that I can check it.

Comment: I can't upload base64 it gets stuck.

Comment: But the base64 opens up if I put it in browser.

Comment: You can make public URL of your `base64` using this site https://textuploader.com/

Comment: No help with that, even textuploader gets stuck.

Comment: Oh! If you have gmail or outlook a/c than upload .txt file & share it as public, to get public url. From Google drive or OneDrive.

Comment: It worked. But now new issue. When I do it in a loop only 1st 3 images are displayed and then I am getting outOfMemory error.

Comment: @Arti - The size of Bitmap is fixed. If it is exceeding then it would throw exception. You need to resize it.  For more information visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133645/imageview-outofmemoryexception