# How Remove This Exception And What's meaning of this Exception?

Tags: android, exception

In My applicatin occure this exception please suggest me How I can Rectify this Exception:-
I have been Tried to change in Imageloader code as but that not success.

```
 //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
        /*
         *  options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

         * 
         * 
         * 
         * */
     // Calculate inSampleSize
        o.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(o,100,100);
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
       // final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        //int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
  //            int scale=1;
//            while(true){
 //                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
 //                    break;
 //                width_tmp/=2;
 //                height_tmp/=2;
//                scale*=2;
 //            }

               //decode with inSampleSize
           //            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
              //            
            //            o2.inSampleSize=2;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
```

What wrong in above code because  Exception occure in this section...

```
  06-28 10:53:36.676: E/dalvikvm-heap(595): 960000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
  06-28 10:53:36.806: E/GraphicsJNI(595): VM won't let us allocate 960000 bytes
 06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
 06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
 06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
   06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
    06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.rentfaster.utilities.ImageLoader.decodeFile(ImageLoader.java:161)
    06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.rentfaster.utilities.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:94)
    06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.rentfaster.handler.DetailPhotoHandler.imagefecher(DetailPhotoHandler.java:211)
   06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):   at com.rentfaster.handler.DetailPhotoHandler.characters(DetailPhotoHandler.java:153)
   06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:165)
   06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:518)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    at or g.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
 06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    at com.rentfaster.home.PropertyDetail$Photostask.doInBackground(PropertyDetail.java:1174)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    at com.rentfaster.home.PropertyDetail$Photostask.doInBackground(PropertyDetail.java:1)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
  06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

Comment: Showing your code would help get an answer. You've run out of memory loading a bitmap. This can be caused by the load operation itself or (more likely) by a memory leak somewhere else in your system.

Comment: You can see my [answer][1] on the same issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115) on the same issue.

If you want some more help, please let me know.

Thank you :)

**UPDATE:**

You have used:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
```

This method creates a bitmap and returns the bitmap, you are not catching that bitmap.

you should use something like:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
```

You should create all the options first and then call the `decodeStream()` method. There is no effect of creating options after calling this method.

You have used options, but always try to use all possible **options** that you can use, like following:

```
options.inScaled = true;
options.inPurgeable = true;

// to scale the image to 1/8
options.inSampleSize = 8;
```

Always call the **`bitmap.recycle()`** method as soon as you have used bitmap.

If all these solutions does not work, then as I have suggested, use `MAT for eclipse` plugin, because, certainly u'd be having a memory leak in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Error happen for this reason...

06-28 10:53:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(595): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

It help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a memory leak, Bitmaps in your activity are not properly deallocated by the garbage collector because they have crossed references to their activity. Try to monitor the heap usage  via the `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` command