# out of memory exception with multilanguage support in app

Tags: android

i am working on my one applciation in which i have 9 tabs with tabhost and activitygroup

with 9 tabs my applcation works perfectly but when i added 10 th tab for language screen i have 7 lanuages in dropdown on changing of dropdown values application language is changed but after that when i navigating screens 4 to 5 times

**Out of memory exception occurs** 
here is error exception

Exception

```
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at com.milagemaster.Activity_setup.onCreate(Activity_setup.java:51)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     ... 31 more
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:171)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     ... 39 more
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:447)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1705)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
07-04 13:41:57.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4866):     at
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/relroot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.milagemaster.utility.Header
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeHome"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/title" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAddData"
                style="@style/TitleTextAppearance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/results"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Send Mail"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrscroll_barsMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lnrTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgShadow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_title" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_barsMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lnrTitle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeResult"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="top" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativetitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_blue" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtResultTitle"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/vehcile"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spnSelectVehicle"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/dropdown"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--
                     <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtResultTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_blue"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="your vehicle"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />


                -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameresult"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativetitle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_box"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:text="(mpg/kpl)"
                        android:textColor="@color/mileage1"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtAvg"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage1"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtAddFirstTime"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lnrLifeTime"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtResultLifeTime"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="14dp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtLifeMileage"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:text="(mpg/kpl)"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage1"
                            android:textSize="14dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/frameresult"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/themed_btnlarge"
                    android:text="@string/savelocationasfavorite"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSave"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnChartMilage"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/themed_mileagechart"
                        android:text="@string/mileagechart"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnCostGallons"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/themed_fuelcost"
                        android:text="Cost/unit Chart"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnChartFuel"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/themed_fualpricechart"
                        android:text="@string/fuelchart"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnShare"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/frameButton"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/themed_btnlarge"
                    android:text="@string/share"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please give me some suggestion

Comment: How did you use the custom fonts?

Comment: sorry but not yet any answer solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

This OOME exception is occurring because of bitmaps.

Are you calling `bitmap.recycle()` method after using bitmap? You should always call this method as it will free up the resources held by the bitmap.

This error occurs because of memory leak in your code. You need to find it. You can use MAT (plugin) for eclipse software to find the memory leak.

For detailed info, please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115) on the same.

If this doesn't solve the problem, please let me know, we'll find some other solution.

Thank you :)

Comment: we are not using too much bitmap that cause bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Comment: we are testing our app in motorolla milestone 2.1

Comment: if you are not using too many bitmaps, then the size of bitmaps might be large.

Comment: total size of bitmap in my app is just 1.5 mb is there a problem with that?

Comment: this is certainly occurring due to memory leak, as you have said that navigating 4 to 5 times, occurs this error.

Comment: yes its a memory leak i dont find a way to solve this , i am trying to solve this issue for last 2 days

Comment: Even I was stuck once while finding a memory leak, MAT for eclipse solved it straight away. Try this plugin, it will surely solve your problem.

Comment: i have downloaded it but how to use it ,it does not show me any log

Comment: follow the steps from http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

First look into this exception `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>`
 
you have an error in one of your layout `.XML`

Comment: its not a problem of  my one xml i have 10 activties, this error comes any time in any of the activty with out of memory

Comment: There is something wrong in your layouts. This error must not be there. :)

Comment: I have given my layout please see above

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is recreating of the activity. If you watch carefully when you change your language, The current activity died and Android re-create a new Activity with new Language. It is similar to changing screen orientation, so it will be ok if you manage your memory usage.
Make sure you don't have memory leak, by doing the following. There is a [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) video

- make sure your activity is thread safe
- when first activity died, check if the resource are dealloc properly

Comment: I have used tabhost with activitygroup is there problem with that?

Comment: Try to conserve memory usage and prevent memory leak. you can try to transfer your heavy object via onsaveinstancestate().

Answer (score 0):

You may be using large bitmaps as backgrounds. The Out of memory exception occurs during layout inflation. Use smaller bitmaps if possible.