# "Out of VM budget" on 2.3.3 and "trying to use recycled image" on 2.2 with the same code

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory

I am tired of trying every possibility in stackoverflow and googled alot......
not getting what i want.

```
bt=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), dressarray[indexdress],options);
//Background1 = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(dressarray[indexdress]);
bt1=Bitmap.createBitmap(bt);
dress.setImageBitmap(bt1);
```

i have this code in various if else conditions... dress in code is `ImageView`
there are lots of images on my screen..
there are 10 `ImageButtons` and for those i have 1 `onClick` method which performs above operation on particular `ImageView` by checking which button is pressed.

at last i call a method to recycle bitmap(which is my last variation before asking question) inside `onClick`.
call to that method is the last line in `onClick`

here is the method to recycle

```
public void callrecycle()
    {
        bt.recycle();
        bt=null;
        bt1=null;
        System.gc();
    }
```

now problem is i hav an emulator with HTC EVO screen density and resolution with platform 2.3.3 an a second emulator with density 180 resolution 320X480 and platform 2.2

on 2.3.3 i get an error

```
07-06 10:42:41.898: D/dalvikvm(420): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 52% free 2611K/5379K, external 19034K/19732K, paused 55ms
07-06 10:42:41.918: E/dalvikvm-heap(420): 1382400-byte external allocation too large for this process.
07-06 10:42:42.028: I/dalvikvm-heap(420): Clamp target GC heap from 25.682MB to 24.000MB
07-06 10:42:42.028: E/GraphicsJNI(420): VM won't let us allocate 1382400 bytes
07-06 10:42:42.028: D/dalvikvm(420): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 52% free 2611K/5379K, external 19034K/19732K, paused 35ms
07-06 10:42:42.028: D/AndroidRuntime(420): Shutting down VM
07-06 10:42:42.028: W/dalvikvm(420): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:432)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:383)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:367)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at com.internetdesignzone.dressup.DressUp$1.onClick(DressUp.java:334)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-06 10:42:42.050: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 10:42:44.968: I/Process(420): Sending signal. PID: 420 SIG: 9
```

and on 2.2 aget an error with same piece of code

```
07-06 10:35:37.929: D/dalvikvm(351): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3K, 52% free 2620K/5379K, external 6273K/7166K, paused 59ms
07-06 10:35:38.249: D/AndroidRuntime(351): Shutting down VM
07-06 10:35:38.271: W/dalvikvm(351): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@4051e4c8
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:955)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1044)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:325)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:854)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-06 10:35:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 10:35:40.789: I/Process(351): Sending signal. PID: 351 SIG: 9
```

can anybody tell me the reason?
and please tell me how can i reuse recycled bitmap.
i don want to reduce the quality of bitmap.

the options i am passing have

```
inPurgeable=true
inInputShareable=true
```

Note: if i dont use Bitmap thing and directly write `dress.setImageResource(dressarray[indexdress]);`

the app works like a champ in 2.2 but closes with Out Of Budget on 1st click on 2.3.3
and dressarray[indexdress] is an array of images containing R.drawble.imgid and all are PNG images

Comment: please see my answer on same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115

Comment: My orientation is fixed to portrait and codelog link not working

Comment: i getting dumb day by day now because of this thing.... @Shrikant if you have any code snippent of Weakreference please give me a link

Comment: I had the same issue, and I solved it by setting (bitmap = null) after I used them. In this way, your GC will remove them instantly. If I use recycle(), I had the same error about using the recycled bitmap

Comment: @osayilgan i also tried removing recycle but it only wors for 2.2 in 2.3.3 it gives OOM after fixed number of clicks

Comment: tried with WeakReference but still OOM

Comment: hi siddhesh! If none of the solution is working for you then there is certainly a memory leak in your code.. Please install MAT to determine the memory leak.

Comment: @Shrikant taking too much time to install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue at that time by using downgraded images.

You can avoid this error by using `inSampleSize` & `inPurgeable` in options.
and **reusing** the same `Bitmap` variable and making it `null` after every use.

call `System.gc()` wherever possible. it doesn't call gc but gives hit that it can be started.

`inPurgeable` will make ur bitmap object cleanable while doing `gc()`.

`inSampleSize` will downgrade bitmap so use a proper value.

also you can **resize** your bitmap while creating so that it can reduce its size. use `createScaledBitmap()`

Hope it help others.