# Memory issues when working with media thumbnails

Tags: android, bitmap, thumbnails, mediastore

I'm trying to find an effective way of working with media thumbnails returned from the `MediaStore`. Actually, there are two kinds of thumbnails: `MICRO_KIND` which is square and has 96x96 size independent of the device or platform; and `MINI_KIND` which is around 512x384 for a landscape image, and around 288x512 for a portrait image, also device- and platform-independent. Now, I'm using all the best practices for asynchronous `Bitmap` loading, recycling and caching, and actually my application works just fine when I use `MICRO_KIND`. Anyway, this is not what I want, especially for tablets, where such small images look poor. I've tried using `MINI_KIND`, but it exceeds memory limit pretty quickly, nevermind the implementation. Another trouble is that portrait images have portrait thumbnails, and I need them all to be rectangle landscape. I've tried cropping and resizing `Bitmaps` keeping the aspect ratio, but it gives me even more headache, since for every operation with a `Bitmap` a copy is created and nevermind I'm always using the `Bitmap.recycle()` method, `OutOfMemory` kills me over and over again. I'm looking for an elegant and memory efficient way of creating thumbnails of strictly specified size and orientation, using those queried from `MediaStore`. Would highly appreciate any help and references.

Comment: You may have memory leak, check your code with [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are saying, you have used everything from cropping to recycling, now try with `WeakReferences` as well.

If this also does not help, then you may have memory leak in your code.

Please see my answer on same issue: [bitmap size exceeds Vm budget error android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115)

Its a generic answer, try with all methods that I have mentioned. One of them should work for you :)

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, should take a look.