# Android FragmentStatePagerAdapter outofmemoryerror

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hi I am developing an android magazine application.

It has many pictures. In application I show each picture in full screen and the user can swipe between pictures.

I used `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Every thing works fine. When I rotate the device first time it also works fine.

But if I try it several times it give an error. The error is `outofmemoryerror`.

The adapter for viewpager in `horizontal` and in `portrait` is different.

Anybody help what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Bitmaps`, the memory held by Bitmap doesn't get freed by GC, we manually have to release the memory by calling `bitmap.recycle()`.

Please see my answer on same issue: [bitmap size exceeds Vm budget error android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115)

It has generic answer to this issue.

Comment: I have solved the problem. When the orientation of the device changed the FragmentPagerAdapter shows page from 0. I prevent creating from page 0. It create page where I need. for example my page number in landscpae is 5 when I turn device in portrait I must show again page number 5. But FragmentStatePagerAdapter shows page from 0 and 1.

Comment: This is a different question. Please ask this question separately. Please accept this answer if it has solved your first problem. Thank you :)