# another 'bitmap size exceeds VM budget'

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)
>   [OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

I know that there are many topics about this allready, but whatever I try it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried several onDestroy tricks including recycling the bitmap, putting it to null, etc etc.
Not sure if my code is any different than other situations? It kind of seems that way...
I'm using the TouchImageView extend so I can use pinch zoom so maybe that makes it more complex?

Anyway here's my code. Could anyone please point out how I can fix this (btw without downscaling the bitmap) please?

```
    public class PageActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.page);

            Intent parent = getIntent();
            int pagenumber = parent.getIntExtra("pagenumber", 1);
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("page"+pagenumber , "drawable", getPackageName());

            TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(this);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            img.setMaxZoom(4f);

            LinearLayout rootview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.RootView);
            rootview.addView(img);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I notice onDestroy() isnt begin called because I'm using a tabhost. So I've tried putting a ontablistener in it and call ondestroy manually that way, but then it gets called when the activity isnt even started yet so I tries to use a recycled bitmap when I put the recycle() stuff in it :S

Comment: I've made up a great way to stop the memory leak, so can this topic be reopened so I can post it?
I think others might benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying, you have used everything from cropping to recycling, now try with WeakReferences as well.

If this also does not help, then you may have memory leak in your code.

Please see my answer on same issue: [bitmap size exceeds Vm budget error android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737582/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-android/10738115#10738115)

Its a generic answer, try with all methods that I have mentioned. One of them should work for you :)

Thank you.

Comment: the weakreference trick doesnt seem to work

Comment: Try using all the options from BitmapFactory.Options while creating Bitmaps. Also consider scaling the bitmap to smaller size as it might be taking too much memory.

Comment: I've tried that but then the images look like crap.

Comment: Have you checked whether your code has memory leak or not?

Comment: Yes. When I click on the tabs in mijn tabhost I see the external getting bigger and bigger. After 4 pageactivity's it has 4 images loaded in memory and it crashes

Comment: Have you used MAT? Certainly you are having a mem leak. Are you using a context of an activity that is already finished?

Comment: Ive found the answer, but to bad someone closed this thread....now I cant post it :P