# Am I using AsyncTask correctly?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was reading the book "Professional Android" and they say the following regarding `AsyncTask`:

> It's important to note that Async Tasks have no built-in understanding of the life cycle of the components they're running with. This means that if you are creating an `Async Task` in an `Activity`, to avoid memory leaks you should define it as static (and ensure it doesn't hold a strong reference to an `Activity` or its `Views`).

To test `Async Task` I wrote the following code that should reverse a string in the background and show the string being built gradually by updating a `TextView`. Am I using strong reference here?

```
package com.example.leo.test01;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private TextView textView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_reversed_string);

        new reverseStringAsync(textView).execute("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    }

    private static class reverseStringAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private TextView textView;

        reverseStringAsync(TextView textView) {
            this.textView = textView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute()");
            textView.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground()");
            int n = strings[0].length();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i  <= n; i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(strings[0].charAt(n - i));
                publishProgress(stringBuilder.toString());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate()");
            textView.setText(values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute()");
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be sleeping on an AsyncTask like that.  The reason-  all AsyncTasks share the same thread (unless you call executeOnExecutor).  This means that if one task is running, no other AsyncTask in your system can run until its finished.  As a result, an AsyncTask should be very quick and isolated.  Something that's going to be sleeping N times for a second each time should not be an async task.

For something like this, the right answer is probably just posting a delayed message to a Handler and running it on the UI thread with each delay.

For something that's actually doing CPU intensive work but needs to sleep like that, use a Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your async task is capturing a strong reference to the `Activity`'s `TextView`. Perhaps to avoid memory leaks, you should wrap the `TextView` instance with a `WeakReference<TextView>`.

More on that over here : [How to use WeakReference in Java and Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243215/how-to-use-weakreference-in-java-and-android-development)

Comment: This isn't really a problem if the length of the AsyncTask is bounded.  Yes, it may make a reference to the Activity last a few more seconds, but in practice that generally isn't worth the effort of guarding against (and if its long enough to be a potential problem, it shouldn't be done in an AsyncTask for other reasons).