# Creating an application specific keyboard

Tags: android, android-input-method

I want to create a custom keyboard which will be available in my application only (It's used jut for a single `EditText` in one activity), and I was wondering what would be the best way to do so. Here are my specifications for the keyboard:

- It should always be displayed in the activity it is used (Regardless whether the `EditText` is focused or not).
- It will have 2 or more keys layouts (Similar to the regular keyboard which has letters layout and a few numbers/symbols layouts).
- Some keys may require some special action (Rather than simply adding their `android:codes` key value to the `EditText`).
- It doesn't offer candidates for completion/correction.
- It doesn't offer more than one input type (Like the regular keyboard which has `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`, `TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME` and so on...).

How should I develop it? Should I create a full input method service for it? Or should I create just a `KeyboardView` and add it to the activity's layout? (I want to use `KeyboardView` for the convenience of keys creation and click events handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a one-off thing and not meant as a separate app, You can simply use whatever method is easiest for you (The `KeyboardView` method).

Try it out and make sure it's responsive and snappy. If it works, then simple and easy method would be my recommendation.

Comment: I guess I will use a `KeyboardView` attached to my layout... I asked this question in the first place to see if it is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard). I think the best way is to make a custom layout and inflate it. Theres a tutorial given [here](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html) too.

Comment: Wouldn't `KeyboardView` be a better option? A custom layout is much more complicated in many aspects of the keyboard development.