# Android control 3rd party application using voice

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I have a voice recognition engine working in android. I want to develop an service application in android, which can control 3rd party applications according to the voice inputs. 
For example, when voice recognition returns a text, I want to send it to some textfield in the active screen by using XY coordinates or controller ID in the OS.

I have done similar stuffs on Windows mobile. I am extremely new to android. 
Anyone knows how to perform such operation.

/chatcja

Comment: I think you will have to make an alternative keyboard that allows for that. Short of that It isn't really possible to inject keyboard input into other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give keyboard inputs to apps that aren't your own, the only way is to build your own alternative keyboard. After this, the user will have to select your keyboard as his keyboard of choice so that it shows up whenever textboxes receive focus. You can even listen for voice inputs and parse them to do what you need. These links might help:

Keyboard:

- [How to make a Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)
- [Create Custom Keyboard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284664/create-custom-keyboard-in-android)
- [creating custom android keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091674/creating-custom-android-keyboard-layout)

Voice input:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html
- [Is there a way to use the SpeechRecognizer API directly for speech input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975443/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-speechrecognizer-api-directly-for-speech-input)

Comment: Hi Anup, thank you very much for the answer. My application also needs to tap the given location in the screen. ex. press button using the voice. Is this possible with android ?

Comment: Yes. You can simply pass a click action to the UI element on screen programmatically.