# Creating custom softkeyboard in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I create a custom soft-keyboard in android and how to add custom images in soft-keyboard as like as smiley.

I'm a android fresher please give some examples of custom keyboard creation. I am using android studio 1.3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Custom Keyboard in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284664/create-custom-keyboard-in-android)

Comment: There are plenty of examples like http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615 . Please ask any particularly.