# Creating an IME in Android, how can I only cover one input type and let another keyboard handle all others?

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

I'm following posts like:

[How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android/3480756#3480756%3E)

[Create Custom Keyboard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284664/create-custom-keyboard-in-android)

I was wondering though, is their a way to default to using another keyboard?
IE: I want to only cover the email input, nothing else.  What can I do to make it use the system keyboard, or Swift or another keyboard for all other inputs (Numbers, general text etc.).
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Any help is appreciated, I've not gotten to play too much with this, just want to see feasibility before I start a project.

Cheers,

Justin W.

Answer (score 1):

Using InputMethodService, you can definitely switch to another IME if you want to.

But, once another IME is activated, you cant switch from another IME to your IME. This is for security reasons.

[It's clearly mentioned in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#Security).

> A client application can ask that the system let the user pick a new
>   IME, but can not programmatically switch to one itself. This avoids
>   malicious applications from switching the user to their own IME, which
>   remains running when the user navigates away to another application.
>   An IME, on the other hand, is allowed to programmatically switch the
>   system to another IME, since it already has full control of user
>   input.