# Activity with numeric keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

How to set Activity with numeric keyboard,I know that we can specify numeric keyboard for each controls like this

```
 <EditText a:layout_width="0dip" a:id="@+id/priceTextBox"
              a:layout_height="40dip"
              a:layout_weight="20" a:singleLine="true"
              a:focusable="true"
              a:inputType="number" a:numeric="integer"


            />
```

But requirement is activity itself need numeric keyboard not each controls.How to specify like that? Kindly assist..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923742/1970317

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

An activity can't process input by itself, so what do you want to achieve? A less dynamic screen layout?

Either way, you may want to read about the [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) which allows you to force the keyboard to open, e.g. by calling `showSoftInput(View view, int flags, ResultReceiver resultReceiver)` which also allows you to specify a reveiver for the input. You'll need a View, though. I'd try to set up a view for solely numeric input and hide it.