# To add special keypad to application

Tags: android, css

I just want to add keypad for the application that developed for displaying items alone and the keypad must contain only numbers as well as decimal and cancel button. How i want to create that and where i just want to create coding for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of tutorials and answers on stackoverflow. A simple search will be help full for you!

When i have searched on "How to create a custom keyboard in android", i got these results that i want to recommend you!

1. http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm
2. http://www.winkeywong.com/2011/05/how-to-custom-keyboard-in-android.html
3. [How to make a Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)

I hope that this will help you!