# Android Custom Popup Keyboard

Tags: android, xml

I am a newbie android developer. Looking for ui ideas for a loan app am developing. I saw this from an app. Any ideas how i can implement something like this....
[image: ExpenseManager].
I mean the popup keyboard with the decimal point.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard look here

Comment: Refer this to start with http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's regular dialog (`DialogFragment`) with custom layout to make look as you want.

Comment: Can you please help with a snippet?

Comment: @Marcin , with all due respect to you, do you really think that is an answer? :)

Comment: Yes. It's fishing pole, not a fish. If you can't now search for "android dialog customview tutorial" there's no hope for you anyway :)