# Is there any way to override the device keyboard?

Tags: android, ios, html, windows-phone-8, mobile

I'd like to override the device keyboard on my web page to show either unicode widgets or glyphs from my own .ttf. Is there any way to do this on mobile devices?

[image]

Comment: [num1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard) [num2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)

Comment: Very nice. I need to do it in a web page though.

Comment: OK. I don't know how to do that with html5. The keyboard is usually provided by the specific operating system.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do that with standart html elements, but i'm quite sure you should be able to get what you want if you go full custom and make everything from scratch.
It's not a solution I would suggest though, usually using standard elements prevents wired 'undebuggable' bugs.