# Custom Keyboard for android

Tags: android

I am going to develop custom keyboard. I want to use custom font NOT for keyboard, for anywhere i use that keyboard. For example in Message,Social app like whatsapp and etc.
Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Android custom keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

I think is possible to create your own keyboard layout from a scratch. I haven't it or similar to that yet, so I would recommend you to read carefully this links:

- http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Also on StackOverflow you would find some useful question like this

- [How to make a Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)

Hope it help

Comment: The other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard is from March 2012 and Eclipse is no longer supported (Sept 2017). So a fresh tutorial would help.