# Gif Keyboard for Android

Tags: android, keyboard, gif

How would I go about creating a dynamic Gif keyboard for Android? I would like the user to scroll horizontally across the Gif's and possibly search across them via an integrated search bar in the keyboard

I've seen this link but it doesn't talk about dynamically changing the keys: [How to make a Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

In your InputMethodService there is a callback [onCreateInputView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onCreateInputView())

You can create whatever custom view you want and return in there.
For horizontal scrolling, maybe look at view pager