# How to make a custom keyboard in andorid

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make a custom keyboard in android. is any body help me how to make custom keyboard in android.
and one more question, how to make a emoji button in custom keyboard. i want to use mine own emoji's. is it possible??

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Android custom keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create your own keyboard with emoji's you have to use inputmathod service to create your own keyboard (You can take help from this [link](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard))

[This link also](https://github.com/g1011999/Gingerbread-Keyboard)

Comment: how to use that keyboard. please help me.

Comment: @DanishButt Yo have to run application from your development tool than got to settings than enable your custom keyboard than select your keyboard as input mathod