# Custom Keyboard in Android

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I want to develop a Keyboard in Android. How Should I proceed? Also I wanted to know whether all the popular keyboards used today in Android implement Machine Learning or Natural Language Processing.

Comment: You can work through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939816/3681880) to get a general idea of how to make a keyboard. I don't know what percentage of the current popular keyboards use machine learning.