# Setting the cursor at the start of inserted text with InputConnection.commitText

Tags: android, android-edittext, inputconnection

The documentation for [`InputConnection.commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#commitText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) says that `newCursorPosition` means:

> int: The new cursor position around the text, in Java characters. **If >
>   0, this is relative to the end of the text - 1; if <= 0, this is
>   relative to the start of the text.** So a value of 1 will always advance
>   the cursor to the position after the full text being inserted. Note
>   that this means you can't position the cursor within the text, because
>   the editor can make modifications to the text you are providing so it
>   is not possible to correctly specify locations there.

In [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45005691/3681880), if I enter two characters, then position the cursor between them like this

[image]

and then enter another character, it doesn't matter if I set `newCursorPosition` to `0` or `1`. The cursor is always at the end of the insertion. For example calling

```
inputConnection.commitText("aaa", 0);
```

or

```
inputConnection.commitText("aaa", 1);
```

Both show the cursor like this:

[image]

If I do `-1` with

```
inputConnection.commitText("aaa", -1);
```

I get this

[image]

The `1` and `-1` results are expected as per the documentation. **Why doesn't `0` put the cursor at the beginning of the insertion?** I would expect `0` should be like this

```
inputConnection.commitText("aaa", 0);
```

[image]

but it isn't. Why not?

Comment: Why are you showing two different locations for 0? Perhaps 0 has no effect?

Comment: In the last image I am showing the expected result, not the actual result. @AlexanderHiggins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a defect in the code, but you be the judge.

Take a look at [replaceText()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.java#L829) in `BaseInputConnection`. I believe that this is the code that places the cursor after insertion. (`replaceText()` is called from `commitText())`.

In the referenced code, `a` is the selection start. `b` is the selection end. Since there is no selection in the example and the cursor is at index 1 then `a == b == 1`. Also, the new text (aaa) is not inserted (replacing a selection [a,b]) until after the cursor is moved to the new selection.

`Selection.setSelection(content, newCursorPosition)` sets the cursor position, so for 0 and 1 to produce identical positioning in your example, I would expect the derived value of `newCursorPosition` to be the same for both inputs.

With the cursor positioned between the two 8's at position 1, let's think through the following code:

```
if (newCursorPosition > 0) {
    newCursorPosition += b - 1;
} else {
    newCursorPosition += a;
}
```

For your input of 1, `newCursorPosition` > 0, so newCursorPosition = newCursorPosition + 1 - 1 or 1.

For your input of 0, `newCursorPosition` is not = 0, so newCursorPosition = newCursorPosition + a (0 + 1) or 1.

Since both inputs produce the same value, I would expect `Selection.setSelection(content, newCursorPosition)` to produce the results you see.

<s>I have not followed the code exactly to this location, but I believe that this is the problem.</s> I have followed the execution paths in `BaseInputConnection` for `newCursorPosition = 0` and `newCursorPosition = 1` on a Pixel emulator with API 21 and what is outlined above does hold.

Comment: Rereading the documentation, I can kind of understand the meaning now of "you can't position the cursor within the text". If choosing `0` for `newCursorPosition` could move the cursor to the start of the insert, then this would in fact be allowing you some positioning power. Like you said, it still feels like a defect, but perhaps it is an understandable one.

Comment: @Suragch Maybe the documentation should read: " If >= 0, this is relative to the end of the text - 1; if < 0, this is relative to the start of the text." However, I do think that the cursor could be placed at the start of the insert, but this must not be something in high demand.(I have incorporated your clarifying explanation of `a` and `b`.)