# How to commit composing text to an InputConnection when the user changes the selection

Tags: android, custom-keyboard, android-input-method, inputconnection

I am making a [custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard/45005691#45005691) and have to set composing text before committing it. This is described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204305/set-composing-text-on-an-edittext-from-a-custom-keyboard-in-android).

I know how to commit text in general

```
inputConnection.commitText("text", 1);
```

But I don't know how to commit it if the user changes the cursor location by touching another part of the `EditText`. From observing other keyboards I know it is possible because they do it. But in my keyboard if I have

```
inputConnection.setComposingText("text", 1);
```

and then change the cursor position, the composing span is left. Any future changes will replace the composing span, not be entered at the new cursor position.

The post [Android EditText listener for cursor position change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962366/android-edittext-listener-for-cursor-position-change) gives some ideas for what you could do to an `EditText`, but inside the custom keyboard I don't have access to the `EditText` except for what the `InputConnection` gives me.

How do I handle know when the cursor/selection has moved?

*I [keep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45204305/3681880) finding the answer to my question after I have started writing it. I will post the answer below.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor (`EditText`, etc.) calls [`updateSelection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#updateSelection(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) on the [`InputMethodManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html), which in turn notifies the [`onUpdateSelection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onUpdateSelection(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) listener. Thus, the keyboard can override `onUpdateSelection` and take care of the unfinished composing span there.

To handle an unfinished composing span you can use [`finishComposingText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#finishComposingText()) on the `InputConnection`. This will remove the composing span and commit whatever text was in the span.

Here is how it is implemented in the [sample Android soft keyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java#274):

```
/**
 * Deal with the editor reporting movement of its cursor.
 */
@Override public void onUpdateSelection(int oldSelStart, int oldSelEnd,
        int newSelStart, int newSelEnd,
        int candidatesStart, int candidatesEnd) {
    super.onUpdateSelection(oldSelStart, oldSelEnd, newSelStart, newSelEnd,
            candidatesStart, candidatesEnd);

    // If the current selection in the text view changes, we should
    // clear whatever candidate text we have.
    if (mComposing.length() > 0 && (newSelStart != candidatesEnd
            || newSelEnd != candidatesEnd)) {
        mComposing.setLength(0);
        updateCandidates();
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (ic != null) {
            ic.finishComposingText();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/widget/Editor.java#1604

```
int candStart = -1;
int candEnd = -1;
if (mTextView.getText() instanceof Spannable) {
  final Spannable sp = (Spannable) mTextView.getText();
  candStart = EditableInputConnection.getComposingSpanStart(sp);
  candEnd = EditableInputConnection.getComposingSpanEnd(sp);
}
```