# Can I use the Android InputMethodManager on a custom in-app keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-keyboard, inputmethodmanager

The `InputMethodManager` is a service that apps can use to interact with the system keyboards. Editors like `EditText` also use it to indirectly notify the keyboards of changes (for example, [`updateSelection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#updateSelection(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))).

I can get a reference to the `InputMethodManager` like this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

My problem is that this seems to be just for system keyboards. Can I use the `InputMethodManager` for a [custom in-app keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45005691/3681880)? If it was for just one isolated app I wouldn't care but I am including a custom keyboard in a library that will be used in many apps. I need a standard way for editors to communicate with the keyboard.

Do I have to write my own input method manager or is there a way to use the standard `InputMethodManager` with my custom in-app keyboard?

**Update**

Here are some clues for how I might implement my own custom input method manager if there is no way to use the standard one.

- `InputMethodManager` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html)) ([source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.java))
- [`InputMethod` interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethod.html)
- [`InputMethodSession` interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodSession.html)
- [`KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener` interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html) (keyboards implement it)
- `InputMethodService` (keyboards extend this) ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html)) ([source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/fb13abd800cd610c7f46815848545feff83e5748/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.java))

Comment: I decided to go the route of making my own custom input method manager. I don't think it is possible to use the system `InputMethodManager` because it involves security issues with the phone. However, I added the bounty just to make sure before I completely abandon the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement yours.

> InputMethodService provides a standard implementation of an InputMethod, which final implementations can derive from and customize. See the base class AbstractInputMethodService and the InputMethod interface for more information on the basics of writing input methods.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Because if you inherit from `InputMethodService`, your keyboard will be available for other apps. There is only one way to create  in-app keyboard, it is using simple `View` in your layout. In this example 
 [custom in-app keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard/45005691#45005691) they use `InputMethodManager` to connect to `EditText`.

Comment: Sorry, First time I was wrong and didn't understand your question. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The example you linked to is my example. It doesn't use `InputMethodManager` to connect to `EditText`. It just connects it directly. But I wanted to use the `InputMethodManager`, which is what led to this question here.

Comment: @Suragch Without inheriting from InputMethodManager you can't get access to keyboard