# How to prevent keyboard from closing when bottom dialog is open?

Tags: android, dialog, keyboard, bottom-sheet

Is there a way not to close keyboard, but just show dialog insted of keyboard(over it). After dialog is closed I need to continiue typing without opening keyboard again?

[image]

This dialog is simple child of BottomDialogSheet:

```
public class BottomPage extends BottomSheetDialog {
    public BottomPage(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);

        View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet, null);
        setContentView(v);
    }
}
```

I've already got implementation with Popup window that covers the keyboard with other layout, but there is same problem when I first opent popup and after that press the edit text to show keyboard - popup hides, keyboard shows. How can I prevent it, and let keyboard show without popup hiding?
[image]

Comment: check this out; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to keep the keyboard on the screen.

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Play with the arguments of **setSoftInputMode()** to get some other effects.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it that simple. You have to get `window` and `keybord` height to do that.

Look at this library and make your own:
https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

Comment: I've got keyboard height and my implementation works same as in that library. Actually in library same problem with keyboard hiding.
I don't know how can I make keyboard don't hide itself and show dialog with keyboard on screen, but covered with dialog or popup

Comment: get a window object and add your view there it won't affect keyborad

Comment: I can't find way to do that without asking user's permission... Is there simplier way to do that?