# How to create a smart keyboard?

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I am working on an application where I need a custom keyboard. Custom means not customizing the keys but I need to show different layouts inside the keyboard itself. I am attaching an image of what I am looking for please guide me how can I achieve this.

Any clue or suggestion will be appreciated[image],

Comment: Lots of examples of soft keyboards you can modify in the GitHub [AnySoftKeyboard](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard),  [AndroidCustomKeyboard](https://github.com/blackcj/AndroidCustomKeyboard) ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard)

Comment: @JonGoodwin I wanted to put fragments and custom layouts ion the keyboard itself.

Comment: Thanks, Jon and Safiyya.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution, earlier I was making the mistake to make keyboard as a parent layout now I redesign my XML to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview" />


    <include
        layout="@layout/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/keyboard1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my onCreateInputView method will look like this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_layout, null);
        kv = (KeyboardView) layout.findViewById(R.id.keyboard1);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return layout;
    }
```