# XmlPullParserException: Meta-data does not start with input-method tag (Android custom keyboard)

Tags: android, custom-keyboard, android-input-method

While working on another project, I noticed an exception pop up in logcat for a previous test keyboard I had made (based on the Going On section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939816/3681880)). It is installed on my phone, but it was not the project I was currently running.

> XmlPullParserException: Meta-data does not start with input-method tag

I retested the keyboard and it still works, so it doesn't seem to be a big problem. However I don't like to leave errors if I can help it.

I couldn't find any other SO questions related to this but I did find where it is called in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodInfo.java#175) for [`InputMethodInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodInfo):

```
String nodeName = parser.getName();
if (!"input-method".equals(nodeName)) {
    throw new XmlPullParserException(
            "Meta-data does not start with input-method tag");
}
```

What would cause this error to happen?

#### Supplemental Code

InputMethodService

```
public class WodeInputMethodService extends InputMethodService implements ImeContainer.OnSystemImeListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ImeContainer jianpan = (ImeContainer) inflater.inflate(R.layout.jianpan_yangshi,
                null, false);
        jianpan.showSystemKeyboardsOption("ᠰᠢᠰᠲ᠋ᠧᠮ");
        jianpan.setOnSystemImeListener(this);

        return jianpan;
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection getInputConnection() {
        return getCurrentInputConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChooseNewSystemKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (im == null) return;
        im.showInputMethodPicker();
    }
}
```

The error is probably hiding deeper than this (like in the custom keyboard view or the [library keyboard](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library/blob/master/mongol-library/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/mongollibrary/Keyboard.java) that it is inherited from), but because of the amount of code involved, I am asking a basic question first. If I find the answer or more relevant code, I will post an update.

#### Stack trace

```
04-26 10:30:13.466 855-880/? A/InputMethodManagerService: Unable to load input method ComponentInfo{net.studymongolian.jianpan/net.studymongolian.jianpan.WodeInputMethodService}
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Meta-data does not start with input-method tag
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodInfo.<init>(InputMethodInfo.java:162)
        at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.buildInputMethodListLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:2732)
        at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService$MyPackageMonitor.onSomePackagesChanged(InputMethodManagerService.java:554)
        at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.onReceive(PackageMonitor.java:402)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

#### Notes

This unfortunately isn't an MCVE question because I can't reproduce the problem. I also don't know the exact part of the code that is causing the problem. I am still asking the question, though, because someone familiar with the error could describe a specific situation that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, the correct way is to have a 'subtype' keyword in the method.xml, but it has to be the first element in the xml: before 'subclass' or 'settings'.

```
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <subtype android:label="French (FR)"
    android:imeSubtypeLocale="fr_FR"
    android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />

  <!-- Specify the class name of the custom keyboard -->
  <subclass android:name=".MyKeyboard" />

  <!-- Specify the settings activity (optional) -->
  <settings android:activity="com.example.customkeyboard.KeyboardSettingsActivity" />

</input-method>
```

Comment: I'm not working on Android native anymore so I haven't tested your answer, but I'll mark it as solved since it worked for you.