# Prevent keyboard in webView

Tags: java, android, webview, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want it to be impossible for the soft keyboard to pop up due to an action in the my webView. That's because I have a custom "keyboard" consisting of buttons below the webView. However, I don't want to completely disable the keyboard for my application, as I have to use it in different contexts. It just shouldn't show up when the user clicks on an input field inside the webView. I also don't want the keyboard to show and instantaneously hide again.

I currently have this in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

I already tried disabling the focus of the webView, but then I can't enter text with my custom "keyboard" either, as the input field of the webView aren't focused.

I also tried this in `onCreate`, but it didn't work (the keyboard still showed up):

```java
View focusedView = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (focusedView == null)
    return;
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (manager == null)
    return;
manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focusedView.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: for me only `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` works. have you tried that?

Comment: Well, it's kind of included in `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateAlwaysHidden"`, isn't it? But I also tried it without the `stateHidden`, but the soft keyboard still shows up.

Comment: Well setting both could yield undefined result. Can you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Oh. That's strange. Update this information in your question so that someone else could answer and doesn't recommend same options

Comment: One more thing instead of passing `0` in `manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focusedView.getWindowToken(), 0);` can you pass `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY`

Comment: @Sagar still doesn't work

Comment: Does it help to define your own (empty) custom keyboard and let the system show that instead of the normal keyboard for the webView? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your `WebView`

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Try this

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Comment: This finally seems to work, thank you! I'll give it a little bit more testing, but you'll probably receive the bounty.

Comment: This also disables hardware keyboards and sending key events to webview

Answer (score 8):

sorry I'm late on this one.

But here is the solution:

Add this in your parent layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Set these two properties of your WebView:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

This works for me :)

Comment: I could have sworn that I had already tried this. Anyway, it seems to work, thank you! However, a slight disadvantage is that the currently selected textbox isn't highlighted anymore. Hence I won't accept your answer as an answer, but if no other solution follows, you'll receive the bounty.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the feedback on it. Ill look for a work around in the meantime, hoping to come up with a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

call this before everything

Answer (score -1):

Paste this in your `onCreate` method after `setContentView`

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

Keyboard wont show when you run this activity.

Comment: As I've already mentioned in my question, this doesn't work. And, btw, it is exactly the same answer as Mechadroids.

Comment: doesnt work ? I have been using this since I learned `android` until now, OMG.

Comment: I can't explain to you why this doesn't work, but the keyboard still pops up with your solution.

Comment: doens't work for me either