# ImageView in Custom Keyboard

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

i like to show an image view in my android custom keyboard (in app not a system keyboard). So far i tried adding one but it does not appear in the view. Do you know whether android supports adding custom views into a keyboard ?

Comment: If you're inheriting from InputMethodService and writing a real keyboard, override onCreateInputView to return whatever view you want, including images.  If you're doing something else we need code.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard