# In app keyboard: different behavior on different devices

Tags: android, android-edittext, custom-keyboard, huawei-mobile-services

I have implemented inside my app a custom numerical keyboard layout (like decribed  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard/45005691#45005691)).

It works like a charm on all devices i've tryed, but on Huawei devices behavior is very strange.
Each time i press e button on my keyboard, current visible text inside textview is replaced with last pressed key (and is not append as i expected). 
So if i try to type "12", when i press "1" everithing is ok, when i press "2" the old char "1" is replaced with "2. What's wrong whith Huauei? I'm going to be crazy with this behavior...

Comment: You're going to need to give us a lot more data about how your numerical keyboard works.  Is it an actual keyboard (an InputMethodService) or is it just an onscreen layout that acts like one?  What code are you actually using to set the edit text in the second case, or to send data to the input connection in the first?

Comment: @GabeSechan i've used the same code of posted link  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard/45005691#45005691).

Comment: So it tries to use inputConnection without actually creating an InputMethodService?  Extremely weird code.  Generally you either make an actual keyboard, or you skip that and just use setText whenever they hit a button.  This combo is unusual.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also facing same issue.