# how to add custom views to android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, material-design, android-custom-view

[image: **enter image description here**]i have a design that have a few buttons. it only appears when keypad is visible. it just come above keyboard like facebook app

Comment: This might duplicate of [how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard)

Comment: no brother, that is about custom keyboard. my requirement is to show a custom view when default soft keyboard is showing..like in my pic

Comment: I think that in that case, it has nothing with the keyboard layout; rather some dynamic view based on keyboard visibility.