# Custom keyboard unable to write into TextView

Tags: android, textview, custom-keyboard

I'm new to Android studio, curently I'm trying to build a custom keyboard within an app(Not Service Keyboard), I manage to done it by referring online resources, but when I try to switched from editText to TextView, my keyboard input just unable to write into the TextView, is there a different method for TextView?

I tried something like textView.setText(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
The app just forced stop in this situation.

This is the editText that works fine.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);  
myKeyboard keyboard = (myKeyboard) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);

editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);

InputConnection inputConnection = editText.onCreateInputConnection(newEditorInfo());
keyboard.setInputConnection(inputConnection);
```

Code below TextView has no respond while pressing on my keyboard.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);  
myKeyboard keyboard = (myKeyboard) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);

textView.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

This is the code that I have tried but app forced stopped.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
myKeyboard keyboard = (myKeyboard) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);

textView.setText(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

For your information, the online resource that I referred to is at [How to make an Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-an-android-custom-keyboard/45005691#45005691)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some alternate way to achieve the result. Add a TextWatcher to your editText, 
and sync it with your TextView. Code shows as below:-

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```