# Change keyboard programmatically, but not the input type

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

**Apple iOS has some methods which can change your keyboard layout(or language).**

Is there any way to make the same thing on android?

I'm not asking about changing the input type:

But what I'm asking is how to change keyboard, but inputType stays the same.(i.e text)

Comment: Check this link.
[How can you make a custom keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android)