# Adding * and # key to the soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

**1) PROBLEM:**

I have an **EditText** in which the user has to enter **USSD** code.

**Problem** is, for entering **USSD** code the user has to switch to **symbol keyboard** (two to three times) which creates a very bad user experience.

**USSD Code Examples:** *345*77#, *333*25#, *123*678# etc.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/field_code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeActionId="@integer/imo_action_search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="phone" />
```

[image]

**2) What I need:**
How can I **replace** the highlighted buttons **(below image)** with * and **#** buttons without using a **custom keyboard?**

[image]

**3) What I have tried!!!**

1) All InputTypes for EditText.

2) Google the issue, the only solution I have found is a *custom keyboard* **but I want to know is there any simple solution**.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android

Comment: I suggest you give 2 separate buttons for `*` and `#`

Comment: @RahulGaur How can I give 2 separate buttons in this system keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

Each keyboard app has its own layout and you can't change it. For example `android:inputType="phone"` has different layouts on `Gboard` and `SwiftKey`.
[image]

**Solution:**
You should implement a custom InAppKeyboard and show it to the user instead of the system keyboard."**[Creating an In-App Keyboard for your Android Apps](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/creating-an-in-app-keyboard-for-your-android-apps-a0a6c6e1e289)**" is a good tutorial that describes how to develop a custom InAppKeyboard like this but you can design your desired layout and use it in your app easily.

[image]

**Update:**
For Using InAppKeyboard with dialog, I have an idea. I developed a custom [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment) which has 2 parts: 
1. The dialog content part
2. The custom keyboard part named `CustomKeyboardDialog`.

You can extend this class and create your custom dialog. Both `setContentView` and `findViewById` methods are available and you can use them to manage your dialog UI. You must override `onCreate` method in your custom dialog implementation and call `setContentView` there. Then override `onCreateView` method, call `findViewById` there and find your EditText and attach it custom keyboard by calling `attachToCustomKeyboard` method. 
**CustomKeyboardDialog.java**

```
public abstract class CustomKeyboardDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private View mRootView;
    private int mContentLayoutResID;
    private View mContentView;
    private CustomKeyboardView mCustomKeyboardView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    final public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_keyboard, container, false);

        ViewGroup contentViewContainer = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.content_view_container);
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(mContentLayoutResID, contentViewContainer, true);

        this.mCustomKeyboardView = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);

        this.onCreateView(mContentView);

        return mRootView;
    }

    public View findViewById(int id) {
        return mContentView.findViewById(id);
    }

    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        this.mContentLayoutResID = layoutResID;
    }

    public void showKeyboard(InputConnection inputConnection) {
        mCustomKeyboardView.setInputConnection(inputConnection);
        mCustomKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCustomKeyboardView.animate().translationY(0).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                updateContentViewSize(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void hideKeyboard() {
        updateContentViewSize(false);
        mCustomKeyboardView.animate().translationY(mCustomKeyboardView.getMeasuredHeight()).setListener(null);
    }

    private void updateContentViewSize(boolean keyboardVisible) {
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) mContentView.getLayoutParams();
        if(keyboardVisible) {
            layoutParams.bottomToTop = R.id.keyboard_view;
            layoutParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET;
        } else {
            layoutParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
            layoutParams.bottomToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET;
        }
        mContentView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    public void onCreateView(View contentView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getDialog().setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(android.content.DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,android.view.KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode ==  android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
                {
                    if(mCustomKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        hideKeyboard();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getDialog().setOnKeyListener(null);
    }

    public void attachToCustomKeyboard(EditText editText) {
        editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    showKeyboard(editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo()));
                }
            }
        });
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showKeyboard(editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo()));
            }
        });
    }

    public void detachFromCustomKeyboard(EditText editText) {
        editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(true);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(null);
        editText.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
}
```

**dialog_custom_keyboard.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view_container"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
    </LinearLayout>

    <mirm.test.testapp.dialog.CustomKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#eee"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**CustomKeyboardView.java**

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button button1, button2, button3, button4,
            button5, button6, button7, button8,
            button9, button0, buttonDelete, buttonEnter, buttonSharp, buttonStar;

    private SparseArray<String> keyValues = new SparseArray<>();
    private InputConnection inputConnection;

    public CustomKeyboardView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_keyboard_layout, this, true);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_5);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_6);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_7);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_8);
        button8.setOnClickListener(this);
        button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_9);
        button9.setOnClickListener(this);
        button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0);
        button0.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enter);
        buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSharp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sharp);
        buttonSharp.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_star);
        buttonStar.setOnClickListener(this);

        keyValues.put(R.id.button_1, "1");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_2, "2");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_3, "3");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_4, "4");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_5, "5");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_6, "6");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_7, "7");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_8, "8");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_9, "9");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_0, "0");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_enter, "\n");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_sharp, "#");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_star, "*");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (inputConnection == null)
            return;

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button_delete) {
            CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            } else {
                inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
            }
        } else {
            String value = keyValues.get(view.getId());
            inputConnection.commitText(value, 1);
        }
    }

    public void setInputConnection(InputConnection ic) {
        inputConnection = ic;
    }
}
```

**custom_keyboard_layout.xml**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_sharp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="#"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_star"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:text="Delete"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_enter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:text="Enter"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Here is an example of custom dialog implementation:
**SampleDialog.java**

```
public class SampleDialog extends CustomKeyboardDialog {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_dialog);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public void onCreateView(View contentView) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        attachToCustomKeyboard(editText);
    }
}
```

**sample_dialog.xm**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:background="#eee">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="32dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Code"></TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:hint="example: *455*415#"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I need input inside the dialog that means the keyboard should open and close like system keyboard. The example you have shared has a fixed "custom keyboard" at the bottom. Do you know any example in which "custom keyboard " is open and closed like the system keyboard?

Comment: Milad thanks, today is Friday I will not be able to test your updated answer, but tomorrow I will definitely test it.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @Milad, currently I am facing another problem due to which I am not able to test it.