# keyboard does not open, when I using an special bottom navigation bar in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

I am using this library in an activity and show fragment on a frame layout when user click on any button of bottom navigation. when user want to type anything in any editText, keyboard does not open by showing this message in logcat:

```
2020-02-06 07:38:20.352 3650-3650/com.tivasoft.myorder W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

this my layout of activity code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:context=".ui.activity.HomeActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/homeAct_frameMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />

<com.etebarian.meowbottomnavigation.MeowBottomNavigation
    android:id="@+id/layBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    app:mbn_countBackgroundColor="#8579e7"
    app:mbn_backgroundBottomColor="#f3f7f8"
    app:mbn_circleColor="@color/colorPrimarySuperDark"
    app:mbn_defaultIconColor="@color/colorPrimarySuperDark"
    app:mbn_rippleColor="#00BCD4"
    app:mbn_countTextColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:mbn_selectedIconColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:mbn_shadowColor="#1f212121" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

when I show fragment on this framlayout andt that fragment includes editext, keyboard does not open.

Comment: make a method inside Handler put time is 1000

Comment: only when i use :   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
in activity, keyboard is open, but i want to adjustResize in activity.

Answer (score 0):

like that you have add

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
                 public void run() {
                   showKeyboard();
                 }
               }, 1000);
```

Comment: refer this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android

Comment: only when i use this line in manifest, keyboard open:
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
but i want to adjust page