# kotlin android Only decimal keyboard

Tags: android

I want to get only decimal keyboard  like this :

[image]

But I get this :

[image]

and this is what I do

```
<EditText
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:digits="0123456789,."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/funding_amount"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_state_blue_light"
            android:hint="@string/pln_amount_placeholder"
            android:minHeight="40sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_color_tutorial"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_16" />
```

if I change I get this :

android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"

[image]

Comment: when ever use `android:digits="0123456789" android:inputType="numberDecimal"` then `@,#` enable or not?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it not work

Comment: Its google keyboard or any  custom keyboard ?

Comment: `it not work` meaning `@,#`  enabled?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya is not enable but I see this buttons

Comment: `is not enable but I see this buttons` I assume this scenario happen some of devices not all

Comment: Have you tried just `android:inputType="number"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom keyboard of android that can input number decimals. Check this link to make your own custom keyboard [How can you make a custom keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android) or Using Library like [here](https://github.com/luoheng158/CustomNumberKeyboard)