# How to create in-app keyboard in android using jetpack compose?

Tags: android, input, keyboard, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

In View system, we can using *InputConnection* to [create in-app keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android#answer-45005691). But in Jetpack compose, i don't know how to do that. Can you help me, please?