# Show custom alphabets - a,b,c,d,e only (Android Keyboard)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

Is it possible to show only 5 alphabets - "a","b","c","d","e" only rather then showing all the alphabets on android keyboard. I tried it by adding below property to edittext but it is not working still it is showing full keyboard.

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
android:digits="abcde"
```

Comment: I think with your changes, the full keyboard will be shown but the user will only be able to select a, b, c, d, e

Comment: @AsthaGarg Yes but Is it not possible to hide unused keys?

Comment: Not possible . You have build your own custom keyboard .`android:digits` does not change anything on keyboard its just accept these digits that all its works like a filter.

Comment: You will need a custom keyboard (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939816/6287910)) or an in-app keyboard (see same link.) You may be able to find a configurable keyboard in Google Play that can do what you want.

Comment: @KapilRajput No, you can build your own Keyboard instead

Comment: @AsthaGarg thanks for the quick response. Going to add the custom keyboard.

Comment: @Cheticamp thanks for the quick response and link. Going to add the custom keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes but Is it not possible to hide unused keys?

No.