# Syncfusion/Xamarin Numeric Keyboard broken - 2 different characters within the same button

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, syncfusion

[Numeric Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cCQt.png)

Has anyone dealt with this problem before? I'm using this in an Android app and I'm not sure why two characters are appearing within the same button. I thought maybe there was a way to individually set the characters within the keyboard but I think this the only thing I can do. I also tried setting the keyboard to Email just to see if the same issue is happening and with that, there's multiple buttons with the same issue:
[Email Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VJox.png)

I pasted the part of the code below in which this is happening. I also want to note that I hooked up a physical tablet to my computer and this is where I'm seeing the issue. When I run it on a Pixel 5 Android Emulator, the issue seems not to be happening:
[No issue on Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYvFH.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Not sure if it's a Xamarin issue, or a Syncfusion issue or where to really look.

```
  <Editor AutoSize="TextChanges"
          BackgroundColor="Transparent"
          HeightRequest="50"
          Keyboard="Numeric"
          MaxLength="3"
          Text="{Binding Degrees}" />
```

I tried looking up Syncfusion docs and Xamarin docs but I can't find any good sources on it. I also tried different emulators and devices although now that I can remember, it didn't work only on my physical devices. A co-worker informed me that it doesn't cause issues for all users/devices but yet it still happens for some. It's more frustrating that it's not a consistent thing so again, I'm not sure the stem of the problem...):

Comment: The keyboard that you see here is a Native Android keyboard so honestly if you ask me this is neither a Xamarin issue nor a Synfusion issue, I don't know if I would even classify this as an issue when you natively invoke keyboards the OS basically creates them so I don't even know if this can be changed at all. the best that you can do is restrict these keys.

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you mean. Thank you for your input

Comment: you can refer to the answer in [How can you make a custom keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android), and achieve it in MAUI by [invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0).

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard you see in your screenshots is a native Android keyboard that has nothing to do with Xamarin or Syncfusion.

As far as I know, there is no way you can change this native behaviour.

Let me know if you have any further queries on this or anything else