# What is the best way to let a child class communicate with the parent class

Tags: oop, design-patterns, communication, observer-pattern

my question is, what is the best way to let a child class communicate with the parent class.
For example:
I have a main class simply called Main, and another class SomeClass.
Now the Main class creates an instance of SomeClass, once the state of the SomeClass-object changes, the Main class should execute different code, depending on what changed.
Yeah I know, that already sounds like the Observer design pattern, but how would I implement it with state changes treated differently?
I'm currently writing an Android app with a database to make it more specific.
In my project I have the main class, a class to connect, read from/write to the database and a GUI container class. (oversimplified, there are a few more)
The main class creates an instance of both the GUI and database class.
Now if I press a button A, it should write A-data to the database,
if I press button B, it should write B-data to the database.
As I think that a gui class shouldn't have direct access to the database, I tried other options, than just accessing the database from the gui-class
Currently, I defined a placeholder abstract class with only one method, that I am just overwriting with the functionality.
So right now I have to create a one-method-class A for the click of button A and a one-method-class B for the click of button B.
It doesn't sound like the best way to me, I mean It's working, but I'd like to improve my code, so if you have any idea, please write your solution. :)

Comment: in my view, it is fine to have one event handler per button. Isn't it? Then it is fine to run code of class that shoud do something. It is fine to me.

Comment: what do you mean by code of class? to access the database class directly from the GUI class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good practice it is better to avoid write code in GUI class. So we can use [MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) here.

Let me show a simple example for your case. This is a `ViewModel` class. View model does not have reference to view class:

```
public class YourViewModel 
{
    public void LoadA() 
    { 
        // here you can interact with your database
    }

    public void LoadB()
    { 
        // here you can interact with your database
    }
}
```

This is your `view` class. It handles button clicking, user interactions with view and forwards to the view model. It has a reference to view model.

```
public class YourView
{
    YourViewModel yourViewModel;

    public YourView()
    {
        yourViewModel = new YourViewModel();
    }

    public void ButtonA_Handler() 
    {
        yourViewModel.LoadA();
    }

    public void ButtonB_Handler() 
    {
        yourViewModel.LoadB();
    }
}
```

If you want to handle many events, then you can try to use this approach [How to: Handle Multiple Events Using Event Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-handle-multiple-events-using-event-properties).

Comment: That sounds like a better way than my current :) to make it clear, ViewModel is a class that only provides the methods that should be called, when buttons are pressed and don't provide changing the GUI elements, is it?

Comment: @Sebastian yeah, you are right! View model should know nothing about your view. Some view animations, images should be handled only in view class. This is a separation of concern or Single Responsibility Principle of [SOLID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692126/cant-seem-to-understand-solid-principles-and-design-patterns)

Comment: @Sebastian I am glad that it helped to you!:)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a good way to approach this would be to use a pattern like that described in this [previous Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975935/java-correct-pattern-for-implementing-listeners#:%7E:text=need%20more%20explanation.-,Here%20are%20the%20steps.,-1.%20Define%20an).

They provide sample implementations there but to apply to your case, you don't need to give the GUI direct access, you can have a parent class which implements the "listener" functionality, and a child (GUI) class which just calls its parent, with those details abstracted away from the child.

If you feel like you need more details/examples on implementing this pattern see https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/java/example